# PL/SQL ORDER BY WHERE a = b

Tags: sql, plsql, sql-order-by

I've got a table Looks like this

```
ID NUMBER,
NAME VARCHAR(2),
Sub_ID
```

Sub_ID can be empty if not, it contains one of the numbers in the ID field.
Data could look like this.

```
ID      NAME              SUB_ID
1       A      
2       B                   1  
3       C                   1  
4       D                   3
5       E                   2
6       F                   1
7       G                   6
```

I want it to sort like this

```
        ID      NAME                 SUB_ID
            1       A      
            2       B                   1  
            5       E                   2
            3       C                   1  
            4       D                   3
            6       F                   1
            7       G                   6
```

I've tried to sort it like this

```
ORDER BY ID ASC, Sub_ID ASC
```

But this didn't worked that's why I'm searching a method to sort with sometihng like this.

```
ORDER BY WHERE(ID ASC=Sub_ID) ASC
```

Comment: You don't have any data where `ID = SUB_ID` so I don't see how that changes your sorting.

Comment: Could you, please, elaborate the *sorting criteria*? Just explain what do you mean by *to sort like this*? Accoording to the sample provided, `SUB_ID` never equals to `ID`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like `connect by` with `order siblings by` might be what you're after:

```
with your_table as (select 1 id, 'A' name, null sub_id from dual union all
                    select 2 id, 'B' name, 1 sub_id from dual union all
                    select 3 id, 'C' name, 1 sub_id from dual union all
                    select 4 id, 'D' name, 3 sub_id from dual union all
                    select 5 id, 'E' name, 2 sub_id from dual union all
                    select 6 id, 'F' name, 1 sub_id from dual union all
                    select 7 id, 'G' name, 6 sub_id from dual)
select *
from   your_table
connect by prior id = sub_id
start with sub_id is null
order siblings by sub_id;

        ID NAME     SUB_ID
---------- ---- ----------
         1 A              
         2 B             1
         5 E             2
         3 C             1
         4 D             3
         6 F             1
         7 G             6
```